# Gstreamer -l flag error with cmake and pkg-config when cross compiling for arm64

Tags: cmake, gstreamer, cross-compiling, arm64, pkg-config

I am using g-streamer with pkg-config on ubuntu 18. I am cross compiling for aarch64 and facing a following error.

```
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so when searching for **-lgstreamer-1.0**
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -**lgstreamer-1.0**
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so when searching for **-lgobject-2.0**
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.a when searching for **-lgobject-2.0**
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so when searching for **-lglib-2.0**
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.a when searching for **-lglib-2.0**
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so when searching for **-lm**
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a when searching for **-lm**
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so when searching for **-lc**
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a when searching for **-lc**
```

I have installed pkg-config-aarch64 also and followed this [thread](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-rs/-/issues/130) but still I can't resolve the error.
Following is my gst version: GStreamer Core Library version 1.14.5

Moreover, I have checked the `.pc` files and they are not available in aarch64 directory. I think I have to install gst for aarch64 but I don't know how can I do it on Ubuntu. The problem only happens when I am cross compiling with pkg-config.

I have installed pkg-config-aarch64 also and followed this [thread](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-rs/-/issues/130) but still i can't resolve the error.

CMake file chunk

```
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(GSTREAMER REQUIRED gstreamer-1.0)

# Include directories
include_directories(
    ${GLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${GSTREAMER_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

#linking GStreamer library directory
link_directories(
        ${GLIB_LIBRARY_DIRS}
        ${GSTREAMER_LIBRARY_DIRS}
)

add_executable(yo_gst tutorial_2.cpp)

target_include_directories(yo_gst PUBLIC ${GSTREAMER_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(yo_gst PUBLIC ${GSTREAMER_LIBRARIES})
```

.sh file chunk for cross compilation

```
export PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS=1
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/bin/pkg-config:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

Pkg-config

```
pkg-config --list-all |grep gstreamer
gstreamer-video-1.0            GStreamer Video Library - Video base classes and helper functions
gstreamer-riff-1.0             GStreamer RIFF Library - RIFF helper functions
gstreamer-1.0                  GStreamer - Streaming media framework
gstreamer-net-1.0              GStreamer networking library - Network-enabled GStreamer plug-ins and clocking
gstreamer-pbutils-1.0          GStreamer Base Utils Library - General utility functions
gstreamer-app-1.0              GStreamer Application Library - Helper functions and base classes for application integration
gstreamer-audio-1.0            GStreamer Audio library - Audio helper functions and base classes
gstreamer-tag-1.0              GStreamer Tag Library - Tag base classes and helper functions
gstreamer-plugins-base-1.0     GStreamer Base Plugins Libraries - Streaming media framework, base plugins libraries
gstreamer-allocators-1.0       GStreamer Allocators Library - Allocators implementation
gstreamer-rtsp-1.0             GStreamer RTSP Library - RTSP base classes and helper functions
gstreamer-check-1.0            GStreamer check unit testing - Unit testing helper library for GStreamer modules
gstreamer-base-1.0             GStreamer base classes - Base classes for GStreamer elements
gstreamer-fft-1.0              GStreamer FFT Library - FFT implementation
gstreamer-sdp-1.0              GStreamer SDP Library - SDP helper functions
gstreamer-rtp-1.0              GStreamer RTP Library - RTP base classes and helper functions
gstreamer-controller-1.0       GStreamer controller - Dynamic parameter control for GStreamer elements
gstreamer-gl-1.0               GStreamer OpenGL Plugins Libraries - Streaming media framework, OpenGL plugins libraries
```

Comment: Pkg-config is not in the include directory
`/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/include$ ls -l | grep pkg-config`

Comment: The fact that during **cross-compiling** a linker searches in the **host native** paths (`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`) signals that your cross-compiling setup is incorrect. Which [toolchain file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling) do you use as `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` option?

Comment: I am cross compiling other programs too and using a separate .sh file  

`-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR=aarch64 \
 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ \
 -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc \ `

There is no issue in the cross compilation. Without pkg-config it compiles properly.

Comment: You should write a proper toolchain file. Also, you might want to set `PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR` to point to the right place, and `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to some non-empty invalid path (like `-`) (empty string works on some implementations, but then doesn't work e.g. on Fedora). I don't know if the cross pkg-config should do it automatically or not, I haven't seen a separate pkg-config binary for cross-compiling before, and just used those variables.

Comment: I have compiled for **ubuntu x64** and it compiled and linked properly

`-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1") 
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-1.0'
--   Found gstreamer-1.0, version 1.14.5
[ 23%] Linking CXX executable yo_gst
[ 23%] Built target yo_gst`

**aarch64**:
.sh file

`export PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS=1
export PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE=${XARCH}-pkg-config
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/bin/pkg-config:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
export PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig`

Comment: Output:
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1") 
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-1.0'
--   Found gstreamer-1.0, version 1.14.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add arm64 architecture by following the [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/430705/how-to-use-apt-get-to-download-multi-arch-library/994650#994650).

1. Install following packages.
   `sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-dev:arm64 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev:arm64 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev:arm64 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:arm64 gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:arm64 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:arm64 gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly:arm64 gstreamer1.0-libav:arm64 gstreamer1.0-tools:arm64 gstreamer1.0-x:arm64 gstreamer1.0-alsa:arm64 gstreamer1.0-gl:arm64 gstreamer1.0-gtk3:arm64 gstreamer1.0-qt5:arm64 gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio:arm64`